# IBM DOORS Analysis Wizard and link modules

Tags: analysis, wizard, ibm-doors

Can you select multiple link modules when running Analysis Wizard? I want to select three link modules from a list of about thirty link modules. I can run Analysis wizard 3x but it would be a better report if I could get all of this link information at once.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the code generated from the analysis wizard concerning a specific link module, you see the following code

```
Item linkModItem = itemFromID("52f965671e816bef-00055da2")
[…]
string linkModName = fullName(linkModItem)
for l in all(o->linkModName) do { […] }
```

You can easily expand this code with a for loop over all relevant link module items

Comment: Thanks Mike --- that is a great idea --- I'll work through this shortly